# Table appears to be incomplete in latex pdf generated

Tags: tables

my code is given as below

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} JP1/JP14 Pins 1 – 8 & Description & JP1/JP14 Pins 9 -16 & Description \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin1 & Ground & Pin9 & D2 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin2 & VCC (+5) & Pin10 & D3 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin3 & Contrast & Pin11 & D4 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin4 & Data/Command (R/S) & Pin12 & D5 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin5 & Read/Write (W) & Pin13 & D6 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin6 & Enable (E1) & Pin14 & D7 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin7 & D0  & Pin15 & VCC (LEDSV+) \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin8 & D1 & Pin16 & Ground \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Pin configuration of LCD}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Are those `rule`s really necessary?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

Smaller version with less lines and typographical fixes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{Pin }l<{:}@{ }l>{Pin }l<{:}@{ }l}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{JP1/JP14, Pins 1--8} &
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{JP1/JP14, Pins 9--16} \\
      \midrule
      1 & Ground             &  9 & D2 \\
      2 & VCC (+5)           & 10 & D3 \\
      3 & Contrast           & 11 & D4 \\
      4 & Data/Command (R/S) & 12 & D5 \\
      5 & Read/Write (W)     & 13 & D6 \\
      6 & Enable (E1)        & 14 & D7 \\
      7 & D0                 & 15 & VCC (LEDSV+) \\
      8 & D1                 & 16 & Ground \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Pin configuration of LCD}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Variant with two tables and caption above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Pin configuration of LCD}
    \begin{tabular}{>{Pin }l<{:}@{ }l}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{JP1/JP14, Pins 1--8} \\
      \midrule
      1 & Ground \\
      2 & VCC (+5) \\
      3 & Contrast \\
      4 & Data/Command (R/S) \\
      5 & Read/Write (W) \\
      6 & Enable (E1) \\
      7 & D0 \\
      8 & D1 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \quad
    \begin{tabular}{>{Pin }l<{:}@{ }l}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{JP1/JP14, Pins 9--16} \\
      \midrule
      9 & D2 \\
      10 & D3 \\
      11 & D4 \\
      12 & D5 \\
      13 & D6 \\
      14 & D7 \\
      15 & VCC (LEDSV+) \\
      16 & Ground \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with two tables]

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear, what "incomplete" means. Assuming, that the table extends horizontal dimension, we can correct it, tightening the columns (option `[H]` removed, because it needs an additional package):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
%\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} JP1/JP14 Pins 1 – 8 & Description & JP1/JP14 Pins 9 -16 & Description \\ 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex}\begin{tabular}{c} JP1/JP14 \\Pins 1 – 8\end{tabular} & Description & \begin{tabular}{c}JP1/JP14\\ Pins 9 -16 \end{tabular}& Description \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin1 & Ground & Pin9 & D2 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin2 & VCC (+5) & Pin10 & D3 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin3 & Contrast & Pin11 & D4 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin4 & Data/Command (R/S) & Pin12 & D5 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin5 & Read/Write (W) & Pin13 & D6 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin6 & Enable (E1) & Pin14 & D7 \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin7 & D0  & Pin15 & VCC (LEDSV+) \\ 
\hline 
\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} Pin8 & D1 & Pin16 & Ground \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Pin configuration of LCD}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```